# ZSH "command not found: z"

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

*iterm2*
*ohmyzsh*

In 'zsh' I can't use 'z' to search folders, appears command not found: z

I try to run

```
source "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/z.sh"
```

and

source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/z.sh

but **doesn't work**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got it!,

First:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

and

```
plugins=(
    git
    z
)
```

exit with :x!

And run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This did not solve it for me. I am using zprezto and added it after the initialization of zprezto, so might have to do with that...

Comment: However I was able to solve it using this nice answer: https://superuser.com/a/998871/169461

Comment: In order to have it work right away you want to issue a `source ~/.zshrc` command

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility，`unalias -a` is put below `source /path/to/z.sh` or `source /path/to/oh-my-zsh.sh`, because `z` is an alias for `_z`

```sh
$ type z
z is an alias for _z 2>&1
```

so, remove `unalias -a` （or comment this line )

or put it above `source /path/to/oh-my-zsh.sh`(or `source /path/to/z.sh`). eg:

```sh
unalias -a
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

or add `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` at the end of `.zshrc` file.